# No route matches error while uploading a file with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a simple file upload form where a user should be able to select a csv file from their machine and then save it to a file folder. I am trying to user Carrierwave and my app is built in Ruby on Rails.

When I try to save the file, I get the error "No route matches [POST] "/customers/new".

Here are the various components.

*/new.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for :dataload, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>

 <p>
   <%= f.file_field :file %>
 </p>
 <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

*/models/dataload.rb*

```
class Dataload < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :file_name, :request_user, :source
    mount_uploader :file, CustomerWarrantyUploader
end
```

*/uploaders/customer_warranty_uploader.rb*

```
class CustomerWarrantyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  def extension_white_list
   %w(csv)
  end
```

*customers_controller.rb (new method; I haven't done anything to this)*

```
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customer }
    end
  end
```

Here are the current routes for customers

```
  resources :customers
```

I am not sure what the issue is, having tried various similar approaches. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because that route really doesn't exist. Resources creates the following routes ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html ):

```
GET     /customers          index   display a list of all photos
GET     /customers/new      new     return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST    /customers          create  create a new photo
GET     /customers/:id      show    display a specific photo
GET     /customers/:id/edit edit    return an HTML form for editing a photo
PUT     /customers/:id      update  update a specific photo
DELETE  /customers/:id      destroy delete a specific photo
```

As you can see, the only POST path is /customers. A simple adjustment to your form should do the trick. Something like the following should work:

```
<%= form_for :dataload, { :url => customers_path , :html => {:multipart => true} }  do |f| %>
```

**Edit:** Adding additional information as a result of user comments.

You will also need to add some logic to your controller, to deal with the uploaded file. Basically, in the Railscast, he states *"Part of the site is already built: there is a page that lists the galleries, with a link to each gallery and a page that shows a gallery’s pictures."*. This apparently includes a new and edit page, as well. The code from his controller ( from the project source code - http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/sources/253-carrierwave-file-uploads.zip ) is:

```
@gallery = Gallery.new(params[:gallery])
```

So, when he added his file, he did it as an attribute on the model, so all he had to add was the `attr_accessible :image` bit to the model to make the controller automagically start handling the image (as it comes through in the same params). As yours is coming through in different params (:dataload), and not as an attribute on the model, you will likely need to add more code than he has, using your current technique. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
@dataload = Dataload.create(params[:dataload])
```

or even:

```
@dataload = Dataload.process_uploaded_file(params[:dataload])
```

Then, you would add a `process_uploaded_file` method to your `Dataload` to kick off your relevant Customer creation logic...

Another thing not really handled, yet, is what will happen when there are errors in the data. For example, what will you do (and how will you present the errors)  if 2 out of 10 entries in the uploaded file create invalid records?

Comment: That's great. No more error and I get a message saying the customer was successfully created. However, the file doesn't get saved in the location specified in customer_warranty_uploader.rb. What is it about carrierwave that I am missing?

Comment: It doesn't really look like you're doing anything with it, in the controller. You most likely need to do something like the following (as well as any other desired logic): 
@dataload = Dataload.create(params[:dataload])

Comment: Also (and I almost had this in my original post, but deleted it), you may wish to reconsider your implementation, somewhat. It may be more desirable to make a new controller specifically for your Dataload object, as it seems that there could be a more distinct separation of concerns. It may be easier to maintain and troubleshoot without the addition of the customers logic, into the fix. In this, I am assuming that there are (at least) two forms on the page.

Comment: You may even consider just putting the Dataload bit into its own page (maybe with a lightbox or something, if you need it on the same page), if it is not tightly coupled to the Customer model, and making it an attribute on the customer form, if it is...

Comment: I do have two forms on the page now. One for adding a customer typing in the info manually and another for uploading a file with multiple customer records. This question is about uploading the latter. I agree that it will be easier to test if it is separate.

My problem is I need to save the file the user selects so it can be loaded into the database. Carrierwave is supposed to do this see railscast #253 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads). Should I call the uploader from the controller? Should I use a completely different approach to save the files? Any thoughts?

Comment: and thank you for taking the time to provide such clear direction. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's the `redirect_to :back` in your `Dataload` model, which must be redirecting to `/customer/new` but keeping the same HTTP action, i.e. a `POST` instead of a `GET`, hence the routing error.

I don't think you should have a redirect there (redirects are the territory of controllers), but wherever you put it, you'll probably need a 303 status code to force a `GET`:

```
redirect_to :back, :status => 303, alert: "your file is being processed"
```

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to):

> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior such as a double DELETE. To work around this you can return a 303 See Other status code which will be followed using a GET request.

Comment: I removed the redirect from the dataloads model and I still get the same error. I tried adding a log message in the model and it never ran, my assumption is I am missing something in the controller. Thoughts?

Comment: I added the code for the new method in my question. It is what was created when I generated it. I know that was not a mention of adding controller code during the railscast I started this with. Maybe I missed something. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

you create file via other controller and must use 

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :dataload, allow_destroy: true`

 and use `field_for` in your form. you also can use the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem